# Viewing Test Manager Fields in TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using TFS and Test Manager 2015.  When I attempt to create a query using either Test Manager or Visual Studios I am not able to see the fields that are in Test Manager.  For example, the tester field that is shown is being pulled from the PBI but I want it pulled from the tester who executed the test case in test manager.  Does anyone know how to expose the tables/fields that are in test manager so I can created queries in Visual Studio?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are no these fields in test case work items. You can not simply run a query to get the info.

> Here is all the [Work item field index](https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/work/guidance/work-item-field-index).
>
> *TCM: Used to support Test case management*

You can only found these info in test point.